# Which file included the jquery library file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, browser

From the chrome developer tool or firebug, is there a way to find out which html or jsp file included my jquery library file?

Right now, there are multiple versions of jquery being included. I want to find out a particular version which was included from where, and i want to find it out from browser.

I could not find the details from the network tab.

Comment: you can use developer tool in browser and find the jquery lib loaded. Press `F12` and check `source tab`

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar - I am trying to find the html file which included that Jquery library. I guess that info cannot be got from source tabs, can we?

Comment: You cannot get the html file but which jquery lib is getting use.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check jQuery version, then according to [this](https://api.jquery.com/jquery-2/) article, you will get jquery version.

this property contains version of jquery `jQuery.fn.jquery`

But if you want to find from which file it gets included, then you have to go through source tab of chrome developer tools or similar from other browsers.

shortcut `ctrl+U` will show you source of your file, from that you will understand from which file it running.

Comment: No sir, I am not looking for the jquery version. Let me give a little more details on this. When a particular page is loaded, there are lot of files getting downloaded. among them are 2 jquery library files, one being 1.4.1 and another 1.7.1 I want to know which html file included the 1.4.1 version.  And I want to find this information from browser.